# How would I use jquery click to fade out an aside section in html from an element in nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I have a page that has a nav bar and aside as in below url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKjJ2.jpg

When I click on the first item in the nav bar which is an image, I want the aside to fadeout or if it is already fade out, I want it to fade in. I am just trying fade out for now using jquery but the event does not seem to do anything.

I tried using class, id, child, find functions in jquery. none of it seem to help

Here is my code:

html

```
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/action-bar.js"></script>

    </head>
<html>
    <body>
        <header class=header>
        </header>
        <nav class=navigation-bar>
            <a href=""><img id="menu-img" class="nav-action-image" src="menu_icon.png"/></a>
            <a class="active" href="#Summary">Summary</a>
            <a href="#Summary2">Preferences</a>
        </nav>
        <aside class="action-block">
            <div class="action-block-element-main">Some text</div>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".navigation-bar").find("#menu-img").click(function() {
        $(".action-block").fadeOut(3000));
    });
});
```

When I click on the first item in the nav bar which is an image, I want the aside bar below it to fade out. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `$(".action-block").fadeOut(3000);` and `href="#!"` and also make sure to properly block your attribute values in quotes `" "`.

Comment: Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/75h4c0o6/

Comment: The code that you suggested is already included

Comment: Take a close look, there are errors in your code. Remove the extra `)` from `fadeOut(3000))` and make it `fadeOut(3000)`.

Comment: got it. I need an eye on the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the fadeToggle method to toggel back and forth. It's not necessary to use find - just target the image. Your img had an empty href which was causing the click to leave the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-img").click(function() {
    $(".action-block").fadeToggle(3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navigation-bar">
  <a href="#"><img id="menu-img" class="nav-action-image" src="https://picsum.photos/50" /></a>
  <a class="active" href="#Summary">Summary</a>
  <a href="#Summary2">Preferences</a>
</nav>
<aside class="action-block">
  <div class="action-block-element-main">Some text</div>
</aside>
```

Comment: This just ensures that the menu-img element has been loaded in the DOM before the click listener is added. If it isn't in the DOM yet, it won't be added. If you have a lot of content, it might not be. This just waits until everything is loaded, then adds the listener. I would put all my initial operations with the .ready function

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
   $('#menu-img').on('click', function() {
      $(".action-block").fadeOut(3000);
   });
})($);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navigation-bar">
     <a href="#!"><img class="nav-action-image" id="menu-img" src="menu_icon.png"></a> 
     <a class="active" href="#Summary">Summary</a> 
     <a href="#Summary2">Preferences</a>
</nav>
<aside class="action-block">
     <div class="action-block-element-main">
     Some text
     </div>
</aside>
```